# What to do if you notice blatantly "wrong" reviews?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

I was absent-mindedly going through reviews and I noticed someone accept an edit that unambiguously added nothing useful to a tag wiki. What should I do about it? Is there any way to privately contact the admins, or should I post it publicly? I didn't see a report button, and would prefer not to cause drama.

Comment: Why not simply correct the edit and improve the tah text?

Comment: @Gamow: I rejected the edit, and it hadn't gone through.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why "accept[ed] an edit that unambiguously added nothing useful" makes you want to *report* a user. Oh no, a change that objectively has no negative effect on anything. Better ban the user.

Comment: @q: I don't want the user to be banned, just to reconsider their reviews. Reviewing is one of the most important tools we have to keep site quality high.

Comment: Yes, and as you said, you rejected the edit and it didn't go through. Why is more action necessary here? Why is it so important to Be The Cops?

Comment: @q: Because on SE sites, the community effectively moderates itself, and I think it's important that we pay attention to what we let through? Just because that specific one didn't go through doesn't mean that others won't. I have nothing against the user in question; if I did the same, I'd prefer to have that pointed out to me.

Comment: Real Talk: SE sites are already wild restrictive and actively hostile to new users. Considering the fact that pretty much every action is reversible, I don't understand this outcry [from people who already have all the necessary protections] for more ways to restrict what users can do *before anything is even a problem*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do let us know about this! You can do so by flagging any one of the user's posts as "in need of moderator intervention":

[image: flag dialog]

Provide links to all relevant reviews, and the appropriate action will be taken if necessary.